# JPA Map Fields to Object without Creating Table in DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, native-sql

I am using JPA, JSF, Spring.

I sometimes have native SQLs which I have to use. They are usually joined with other tables. I don't want to create tables in DB for this purpose and I don't want to map field to Object my own. So for this JPA has and ResultSetMapping but you have use Entity and Entity creates table in DB.

How can use JPA to map field to object for my without crating table(no Entity) or whatsoever in DB easily?

Here is a simple scratch code.

Thanks

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="CustomerResultSetMapping",
        entities = @EntityResult(
                entityClass = Customer.class,
                fields = {
                    @FieldResult( name ="LONG_ID"           ,   column ="LONG_ID"               ),
                    @FieldResult( name ="STRING_NAME"       ,   column ="STRING_NAME"           ),
                    @FieldResult( name ="STRING_ADDRESS"    ,   column ="STRING_ADDRESS"        ),
                    @FieldResult( name ="BIGDECIMAL_PRICE"  ,   column ="BIGDECIMAL_PRICE"      ),
                    @FieldResult( name ="INT_AGE"           ,   column ="INT_AGE"               )
                }
        )
)

@Entity
public class Customer  {

    @Id         Long LONG_ID                ;
    @Column     String STRING_NAME          = "";
    @Column     BigDecimal BIGDECIMAL_PRICE = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    @Column     Integer INT_AGE             = 0;

    /////// getters and setters



}
```

Dao fetching data with Native Oracle SQL

```
public List getCustomerAddress(Long customerId)  {
    try {

        String sql = "" +
                " SELECT LONG_ID," +
                "        STRING_NAME," +
                "        A.ADDRESS AS STRING_ADDRESS," +
                "        INT_AGE," +
                "         (  PRICE * NUM_TIME * (CASE WHEN NUM_TIME = 0 THEN 1 WHEN NUM_TIME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NUM_TIME END))  AS BIGDECIMAL_PRICE" +
                "   FROM T_CUSTOMER C, T_ADDRESS A" +
                "   WHERE C.ADDRESS_ID = A.ID AND C.ID = :CUSTOMER_ID" +
                " ";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql,"CustomerResultSetMapping");
        query.setParameter("CUSTOMER_ID", customerId);
        List resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have added my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working solution.

Integer, Float, Long,... has to be BigDecimal

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;

public class PojoCustomer  {

    BigDecimal  LONG_ID          ; // Long          LONG_ID             = 0L  ;
    String      STRING_NAME      ; // String        STRING_NAME         = "";
    BigDecimal  BIGDECIMAL_PRICE ; // BigDecimal    BIGDECIMAL_PRICE    = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal  INT_AGE          ; // Integer       INT_AGE             = 0;

    /////// getters and setters


}
```

DAO fetching data with Native Oracle SQL

```
public List getCustomerAddress(Long customerId)  {
    try {
        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.append(" SELECT LONG_ID, ");
        sqlBuilder.append("        STRING_NAME, ");
        sqlBuilder.append("        A.ADDRESS AS STRING_ADDRESS, ");
        sqlBuilder.append("        INT_AGE, ");
        sqlBuilder.append("         (  PRICE * NUM_TIME * (CASE WHEN NUM_TIME = 0 THEN 1 WHEN NUM_TIME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NUM_TIME END))  AS BIGDECIMAL_PRICE ");
        sqlBuilder.append("   FROM T_CUSTOMER C, T_ADDRESS A ");
        sqlBuilder.append("   WHERE C.ADDRESS_ID = A.ID AND C.ID = :CUSTOMER_ID ");

        SQLQuery createSQLQuery = getNewSession().createSQLQuery(sqlBuilder.toString());
        createSQLQuery.setParameter("CUSTOMER_ID", customerId);

        createSQLQuery.addScalar("LONG_ID");
        createSQLQuery.addScalar("STRING_NAME");
        createSQLQuery.addScalar("BIGDECIMAL_PRICE");
        createSQLQuery.addScalar("INT_AGE");

        ResultTransformer aliasToBean = Transformers.aliasToBean(PojoCustomer.class);
        List resultWithAliasedBean = createSQLQuery.setResultTransformer(aliasToBean).list();

        return resultWithAliasedBean;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same way, but ResultTransformer is on Hibernate query? not a JPA ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT NEW PojoCustomer(c.LONG_ID, c.STRING_NAME, C.INT_AGE) from T_CUSTOMER c");
```

and then

```
query.getResultList();
```

should return List

You need to create appropriate constructor for class PojoCustomer of course.

Comment: Does it really work? Instead of "T_CUSTOMER" table you should use entity name "Customer", shouldn't you?

Answer (score -2):

```
package ferro.model;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Venclipro implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String registro;
    private String ord_Ped;
    private int prod_Dscto_Remate;
    private String cod_Vta;
    private int item;
    private String prodCon;
    private String anio;
    private String mes;
    private String cat;
    private String descripcion;
    private String subc;
    private String subDescripcion;
    private String producto;
    private String marca;
    private String prod_Descripcion;
    private String vendedor;
    private String cd_Vdr;
    private String cliente;
    private String nombre_Cli;
    private String tdoc;
    private String serie;
    private String nroDoc;
    private BigDecimal tc_Venta;
    private BigDecimal tc_Inv;
    private String cond_Pago;
    private String cod_Mon;
    private String moneda;
    private BigDecimal vta_Unid;
    private BigDecimal vta_Neta;
    private BigDecimal dscto;
    private BigDecimal total_Cprom;
    private BigDecimal vta_Sin_Dscto;
    private String factura;

    public Venclipro() {

    }

    public Venclipro(String registro, String ord_Ped, int prod_Dscto_Remate,
            String cod_Vta, int item, String prodCon, String anio, String mes,
            String cat, String descripcion, String subc, String subDescripcion,
            String producto, String marca, String prod_Descripcion,
            String vendedor, String cd_Vdr, String cliente, String nombre_Cli,
            String tdoc, String serie, String nroDoc, BigDecimal tc_Venta,
            BigDecimal tc_Inv, String cond_Pago, String cod_Mon, String moneda,
            BigDecimal vta_Unid, BigDecimal vta_Neta, BigDecimal dscto,
            BigDecimal total_Cprom, BigDecimal vta_Sin_Dscto, String factura) {
        this.registro = registro;
        this.ord_Ped = ord_Ped;
        this.prod_Dscto_Remate = prod_Dscto_Remate;
        this.cod_Vta = cod_Vta;
        this.item = item;
        this.prodCon = prodCon;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.cat = cat;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.subc = subc;
        this.subDescripcion = subDescripcion;
        this.producto = producto;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.prod_Descripcion = prod_Descripcion;
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
        this.cd_Vdr = cd_Vdr;
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.nombre_Cli = nombre_Cli;
        this.tdoc = tdoc;
        this.serie = serie;
        this.nroDoc = nroDoc;
        this.tc_Venta = tc_Venta;
        this.tc_Inv = tc_Inv;
        this.cond_Pago = cond_Pago;
        this.cod_Mon = cod_Mon;
        this.moneda = moneda;
        this.vta_Unid = vta_Unid;
        this.vta_Neta = vta_Neta;
        this.dscto = dscto;
        this.total_Cprom = total_Cprom;
        this.vta_Sin_Dscto = vta_Sin_Dscto;
        this.factura = factura;
    }

    @Id
    public String getRegistro() {
        return registro;
    }

    public void setRegistro(String registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
    }

    public String getOrd_Ped() {
        return ord_Ped;
    }

    public void setOrd_Ped(String ord_Ped) {
        this.ord_Ped = ord_Ped;
    }

    public int getProd_Dscto_Remate() {
        return prod_Dscto_Remate;
    }

    public void setProd_Dscto_Remate(int prod_Dscto_Remate) {
        this.prod_Dscto_Remate = prod_Dscto_Remate;
    }

    @Id
    public String getCod_Vta() {
        return cod_Vta;
    }

    public void setCod_Vta(String cod_Vta) {
        this.cod_Vta = cod_Vta;
    }

    public int getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(int item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public String getProdCon() {
        return prodCon;
    }

    public void setProdCon(String prodCon) {
        this.prodCon = prodCon;
    }

    public String getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public void setAnio(String anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public String getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public void setMes(String mes) {
        this.mes = mes;
    }

    public String getCat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public void setCat(String cat) {
        this.cat = cat;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getSubc() {
        return subc;
    }

    public void setSubc(String subc) {
        this.subc = subc;
    }

    public String getSubDescripcion() {
        return subDescripcion;
    }

    public void setSubDescripcion(String subDescripcion) {
        this.subDescripcion = subDescripcion;
    }

    public String getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public void setProducto(String producto) {
        this.producto = producto;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getProd_Descripcion() {
        return prod_Descripcion;
    }

    public void setProd_Descripcion(String prod_Descripcion) {
        this.prod_Descripcion = prod_Descripcion;
    }

    public String getVendedor() {
        return vendedor;
    }

    public void setVendedor(String vendedor) {
        this.vendedor = vendedor;
    }

    public String getCd_Vdr() {
        return cd_Vdr;
    }

    public void setCd_Vdr(String cd_Vdr) {
        this.cd_Vdr = cd_Vdr;
    }

    public String getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(String cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public String getNombre_Cli() {
        return nombre_Cli;
    }

    public void setNombre_Cli(String nombre_Cli) {
        this.nombre_Cli = nombre_Cli;
    }

    public String getTdoc() {
        return tdoc;
    }

    public void setTdoc(String tdoc) {
        this.tdoc = tdoc;
    }

    public String getSerie() {
        return serie;
    }

    public void setSerie(String serie) {
        this.serie = serie;
    }

    public String getNroDoc() {
        return nroDoc;
    }

    public void setNroDoc(String nroDoc) {
        this.nroDoc = nroDoc;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTc_Venta() {
        return tc_Venta;
    }

    public void setTc_Venta(BigDecimal tc_Venta) {
        this.tc_Venta = tc_Venta;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTc_Inv() {
        return tc_Inv;
    }

    public void setTc_Inv(BigDecimal tc_Inv) {
        this.tc_Inv = tc_Inv;
    }

    public String getCond_Pago() {
        return cond_Pago;
    }

    public void setCond_Pago(String cond_Pago) {
        this.cond_Pago = cond_Pago;
    }

    public String getCod_Mon() {
        return cod_Mon;
    }

    public void setCod_Mon(String cod_Mon) {
        this.cod_Mon = cod_Mon;
    }

    public String getMoneda() {
        return moneda;
    }

    public void setMoneda(String moneda) {
        this.moneda = moneda;
    }

    public BigDecimal getVta_Unid() {
        return vta_Unid;
    }

    public void setVta_Unid(BigDecimal vta_Unid) {
        this.vta_Unid = vta_Unid;
    }

    public BigDecimal getVta_Neta() {
        return vta_Neta;
    }

    public void setVta_Neta(BigDecimal vta_Neta) {
        this.vta_Neta = vta_Neta;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDscto() {
        return dscto;
    }

    public void setDscto(BigDecimal dscto) {
        this.dscto = dscto;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotal_Cprom() {
        return total_Cprom;
    }

    public void setTotal_Cprom(BigDecimal total_Cprom) {
        this.total_Cprom = total_Cprom;
    }

    public BigDecimal getVta_Sin_Dscto() {
        return vta_Sin_Dscto;
    }

    public void setVta_Sin_Dscto(BigDecimal vta_Sin_Dscto) {
        this.vta_Sin_Dscto = vta_Sin_Dscto;
    }

    public String getFactura() {
        return factura;
    }

    public void setFactura(String factura) {
        this.factura = factura;
    }



}




@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();


Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from UFN_REPORTE_VENTAS_DESDE_HASTA('20543886913','01/07/2015','21/07/2015','1')",
                        Venclipro.class);
        List<Venclipro> list = query.getResultList();


        System.err.println("tamaño : " + list.size());

        for (Venclipro obj : list) {
            System.err.println("Registro : " + obj.getRegistro() + " CD_VTA : "+ obj.getCod_Vta());
        }
}
```

Hibernate:

```
/* dynamic native SQL query */
SELECT
    * 
from
    UFN_REPORTE_VENTAS_DESDE_HASTA('20543886913',
    '01/07/2015',
    '21/07/2015',
    '1')

tamaño : 1648
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00003 CD_VTA : VT00012238
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00004 CD_VTA : VT00012239
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00004 CD_VTA : VT00012239
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00004 CD_VTA : VT00012239
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00004 CD_VTA : VT00012239
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00005 CD_VTA : VT00012240
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00006 CD_VTA : VT00012241
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00007 CD_VTA : VT00012242
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00008 CD_VTA : VT00012243
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00008 CD_VTA : VT00012243
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00008 CD_VTA : VT00012243
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00008 CD_VTA : VT00012243
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00017 CD_VTA : VT00012255
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00018 CD_VTA : VT00012256
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00018 CD_VTA : VT00012256
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00019 CD_VTA : VT00012257
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00019 CD_VTA : VT00012257
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00019 CD_VTA : VT00012257
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00020 CD_VTA : VT00012258
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00020 CD_VTA : VT00012258
Registro : VTGN_RV07-00020 CD_VTA : VT00012258
```